# General Solution for a non-homogenous ordinary differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

The differential equation is $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} - \frac{dy}{dt} -6y = e^{3t} - 3t^2$. I first found the homogeneous solution which I got as
$$y(t) = c_1e^{-2t} + c_2e^{3t}$$
I am trying to figure out what the non-homogeneous part would look like. Looking online I assumed the form would look something like
$$h(t) = Ate^{3t} + Bt^2 + Ct$$
But, upon working this part out I end up with the equation
$$e^{3t} - 3t^2 = 5Ae^{3t} - 6Bt^2 - 2Bt - 6Ct + 2B - C$$
which leads to an inconsistent system

What would the form look like? Also, is the any way to quickly determine what the non-homogeneous part would look like?

Comment: Variation of parameters: consider $y(t)=c_1(t)e^{-2t}+c_2(t)e^{3t}$.

Comment: $Ate^{3t}+Bt^2+Ct+D$.

Comment: I managed to solve it. Thanks! Is there any easy way to deduce what the expected form of the particular function should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have determined, the solution to the homogeneous equation is

$$y_h(t) = c_1 e^{−2t} + c_2 e^{3t}$$

Then we need to find the particular solution $y_p(t)$. We can guess that the particular solution looks like:

$$y_p(t) = Ate^{3t} + at^2 + bt +c$$

Plug this guess expression in the DE, we get:

$$y'' - y' - 6y$$

$$= (A(9t+6)e^{3t} + 2a) - (A(3t+1)e^{3t}+2at+b) - 6(Ate^{3t} + at^2 + bt +c)$$

$$= 5Ae^{3t} - 6at^2 - (6b + 2a)t + (2a - b -6c) \cdots (1)$$

Let $(1) = e^{3t} - 3t^2$, we get:

$$5A = 1$$

$$−6a = -3$$

$$−(6b+2a) = 0$$

$$2a−b−6c$$

These equations are easy to solve. So I will leave you with this.